# can we have multiple proxies in a store in sencha extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am working with sencha extjs 4.1.3 and my question is:-
I have one model and one store in my application but I have two url's from where I need to fetch data, both the urls's have data in same format how can I load my single store with two different urls? Please suggest how these can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill the store from two different urls, but only one at a time, you can always override the proxy url in your load call:

```
store.load({
    url:'theOtherUrl'
});
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ej9

If you want the data from two urls to be in the same store, you can either make two stores which copy their content into a third (this allows you to have the two server calls run simultaneously), or you can call the first url, and on success, you call the second url with the `addRecords` option:

```
store.load({
    url:'theFirstUrl',
    success:function() {
        store.load({
            url:'theSecondUrl',
            addRecords:true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data from two URL's to be in the same store, what you can do is while loading data into the store in success function:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("store name")
store.loadRawData(data,true)
```

Again while loading data from second URL use same code given above. Don't forget to use "true" while loading data into store.true to add the records to the existing records in the store, `false` to remove the old ones first.